# Excel and Time field comparison

Tags: excel

In excel how do I check for a time field being greater than 24 hours and a character field being equal to N.  The time filed is in hours minutes seconds

Comment: please [edit] the post to show some mocked up data and expected output. A two sentence description is not enough for us to be able to know how to help.

Comment: See [this guide](https://www.exceltactics.com/definitive-guide-using-dates-times-excel/#:~:text=days%2C%20or%2041534.-,How%20Excel%20Stores%20Times,as%20that%20decimal%20value%3A%200.041666%E2%80%A6) on how Excel stores time values.